# Dynamic functions R divide last column with the but 1 column in R

Tags: r

I wanna divide the field values & each and every row in the last column with the field values in the last but one column.

The column names can differ so thats why I want a dynamic solution.

Comment: `df[, ncol(df)] <- df[, ncol(df)] / df[, ncol(df) - 1]` ?

Comment: Perfect! Exactely what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you post your comment as an answer to make him mark as correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df[, ncol(df)] <- df[, ncol(df)] / df[, ncol(df) - 1]
```